# Cython how make help() describe methods

Tags: python, cython

When used on cythonized class, help() does not describe methods ‘cdef’.

I’ve tried using @cython.embedsignature(True), but no luck, only ‘def’ methods got described.

How can I make **cinit** described, should I write an empty **init** with proper arguments?